# Thinking in Java. Помогите понять задание: part14.project

Tags: java, proxy, task

> **Проект.** Напишите систему, использующую динамические заместители для реализации транзакций: заместитель закрепляет транзакцию, если опосредованный вызов выполнен успешно (т. е. не возбудил исключений) или выполняет отмену в случае неудачи. Закрепление и отмена должны работать для внешних текстовых файлов, что выходит за границы исключений Java. Уделите особое внимание атомарности операций.

Раз 20 перечитал задание, не понимаю, чего хочет автор... В решебнике для книги нет решения этого задания (скорее потому, что оно идёт не как упражнение).
*Вопрос:* Какой код будет являться эталонной реализацией данного проекта?

---

Ниже пример того, что я написал, но текстовые файлы у меня нигде не фигурируют, а об атомарности операций я даже не понимаю как думать... Если компьютер резко выключить из сети электропитания, то любая операция считайте не атомарна...
Код:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

interface Payer {
    void pay(Object target);
}

class Human implements Payer {
    public void pay(Object target) {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5d)
            System.out.println(target);
        else
            throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

public class TransactionMain {

    public static class TransactHandler implements InvocationHandler {
        private Object proxied;

        TransactHandler(Object realObject) {
            proxied = realObject;
        }

        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
            Object result = null;
            try {
                result = method.invoke(proxied, args);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Shutdown...");
                return null;
            }
            System.out.println("Transaction is committed");
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void castAll(Payer p) {
        p.pay(new String("HelloWorld!"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Payer p = new Human();
        Payer pp = (Payer) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Payer.class.getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[] { Payer.class },
                new TransactionMain.TransactHandler(p));
        castAll(pp);
    }

}
```

Буду рад любой помощи, напишите хотя бы не реализацию, а псевдокод или что-нибудь, что поможет понять мне суть задания :с

Comment: Мне кажется, здесь надо осуществлять запись информации по содержанию транзакции  на диск в текстовый файл и проверить что запись прошла успешно. И только после этого заканчивать транзакцию. Примерно как работают базы данных. Ну и атомарность - соответсвенно раз не будет подтверждения записи на диск в случае ошибки то и транзакция не будет закончена. И работать должно даже если вы выдернете шнур в любой момент. Атомарность - если транзакция состоит в записи 2 строк (например первая Дебет, вторая Кредит), то не должно быть ситуации когда в файле записаласть 1-ая строка и не записалась 2-ая.

Comment: И если много потоков транзакицй, то не должно быть записей таких что в файле сначала идут 1-ые строки у нескольких транзакций, а потом вторые.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант предлагаю такую ситуацию смоделировать: есть банк с клиентами, эти клиенты в несколько потоков переводят деньги друг другу, с учетом того что остаток на счете каждого не может быть отрицательный. И все транзакции должны быть записаны в текстовый файл. Причем все операции должны быть атомарными и пока нет записи на диск операция считается не осуществленной.